# How to style jQuery UI's autocomplete list for mouse leave event?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I created an autocomplete field and I don't want to use jQuery UI's default styles for the appearing list. I already figured out how to set a new background color for the list and for the hover list elements. But there still seems to be a style for the mouse leave event. How can I delete it or at least select it?

I don't want any yellow in that list. ;)

I prepared a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fay2w7g/

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<input id="search_in_cmms">
```

CSS:
//after the jQuery UI stylesheet

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item:hover{
    background-color:  #2ea2cc !important;
    background-image: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $('#search_in_cmms').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the `ui-state-focus` class:

```
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item:hover,
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus{
    background-color:  #2ea2cc !important;
    background-image: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: actually the :hover is useless